# VB6 resetting Tab Index Values - What to do about it?

Tags: vb6

I'm finding that as I change the TabIndex property for several controls on my forms, the VB6 is resetting them to different (not necessarily the old) values as soon as my back is turned. This is becoming rather annoying.

Does anyone know how to prevent this, or if it can't be stopped, what method is used to choose the values (so I can work with it rather than against it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option for dealing with TabOrder in VB6 is to use the [MZTools Add-In](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx).  It's free and in addition to a nice tool for automagically organizing your controls' TabOrder, it has many other very useful utilities.

Comment: that looks interesting. I'll have a go at that when I get a minute.

Answer (score 5):

Edited: To include MarkJ's comment

Are you editing them in the correct order? VB6 automatically changes the `TabIndex` for some controls if you try to set multiple controls to the same index.

So the best way to do it is usually to start with the control that you want to be the last one and set that to 0 or 1 (I can't remember which is the lowest in VB6) and then continue through every other control in reverse order.

Comment: @ho1, Thank you for your answer. I think I'm doing this, although it's easy to get it wrong. I'm also trying to leave gaps between logically-related groups of controls to allow more controls to be inserted later; I think that is where the trouble starts. I'm trying to set the tab index of the go button to be 99 so it will always be last; this gets reset to 53 before my eyes. Leaving it at that value, of course, invites the same trouble later. I was wondering if there was some Studio setting to suppress these changes?

Comment: @Brian: So long so I don't remember now, but I have some vague memory that they have to be sequential. In other words, you can't leave gaps. Don't know about any way to disable it I'm afraid.

Comment: @ho1, perhaps that is the reason. Numbering them sequentially will cause hours of fun later. Oh well, what can't be cured must be endured. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Brian: Just though of one ugly alternative though. If you're not using the `Tag` properties for anything, you could set the tabindexes you want in there instead of the `TabIndex` property. Then at the beginning of the run you could put all the controls into a collection, sort them in order of the `Tag` and then loop through them in the correct order and set the `TabIndex` for each.

Comment: +1. Although the absolutely easiest way is actually to start with the control that you want to be the **last** one and then work through in **reverse** order, setting each one to TabIndex 0. VB6 will automatically renumber them as you go along into a sequential sequence starting at 0. There is also a Microsoft add-in to help set the TabIndex values, but personally I didn't find it useful.

Comment: @MarkJ: Yes, I remember that now when you said it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: When you come to add a new control you just need to set it to the value of the control it goes before. The IDE will then shuffle them all up one to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed written description [(source)](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=321998) of the procedure mentioned [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460436/3195477):

> To set the tab order (`tabindex`) of your  controls:
>
> 1. Select the last control you want to receive the focus.
> 2. GoTo Properties window and highlight `tabindex`.
> 3. Type zero (`0`)
> 4. Then click on the control you want to receive the focus before the control you were just on.
> 5. Type zero (`0`)
> 6. Keep going in reverse order (click control, type zero...)
>
> Each time you set a controls `tabindex` to `0` if there is a control that
>   has a k of 0 it will be incremented by 1 and if there is a
>   control that has that `tabindex` it will then also be incremented by 1
>   (and so on and so on).
>
> What you will find out when you are at the first control that you want
>   to receive the focus is its `tabindex` will be 0 and the next control
>   you want to receive focus will be +1 of that and so on and so on.

(Written by "vb5prgrmr" 25 Jul 02 15:20).